# Semi-Selection of Custom UITableViewCell Corrupts UILabel Drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calayer

Tapping and then rolling your finger off of my UITableView's custom UITableViewCell corrupts the drawing of the contained UILabel.  Neither setSelected: nor setHighlighted: are called. The UITableView uses dynamic prototypes.  Tapping the cell results in normal selection and drawing.  Here is a video showing what happens:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMHQc5tpcOY

I do custom drawing in a subclassed CALayer.  Any guidance in resolving is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by overriding setHighlighted as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style).