# Cannot change UITableView blue highlight color

Tags: ios, objective-c

I set:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

and use the code to highlight a row:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection: 0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
```

The highlight color always blue even I set to gray.  If I set:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

it works fine and no highlight.  But just not work with:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

It just show blue color instead of gray color.  Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Please post code that includes the full method bodies for where you're setting the selection color and performing the selection.

Comment: You are not by chance trying this in iOS 7, are you?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Implement it as follows:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

     [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];       
}
```

**OR**

Set the `selectedBackgroundView`'s color as what you want in your custom tableview cell (which is a subclass of UITableViewCell):

```
UIView * selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
[selectedBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // set color here
[self setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
```

or you can configure it in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
//...
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
//...
```

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  I use a custom cell.  Look like setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray doesn't work with custom cell.

Comment: Also, you don't need to set the frame, so the shortest way to set the selection color is these two lines in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:
`cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init]; cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`
(Add an autorelease to the init if you aren't using ARC.)

Answer (score 15):

Note that in iOS 7, using

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];

will not work as expected, because in iOS 7 this is now gray, even if you pass the constant above. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle

Answer (score 5):

Just add this in your method its work for me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
....
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(76.0/255.0) green:(161.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]; // perfect color suggested by @mohamadHafez
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
....
return cell;
}
```

if you have any question feel free to ask

Comment: This is a good answer.  It gives you the right blue color if that is that color you are looking for.  In my case the background was coming up gray when I was specifying the default blue color (UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue).

Comment: Apple has deprecated the blue style, without using the word deprecated. [UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.blue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/selectionstyle/blue) "Blue = The cell has a default background color when selected"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do this sort of configuration either in InterfaceBuilder or in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: yes.  I first did in IB and didn't work.  Then, I did in cellForRowAtIndexPath and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make a global search of "UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue" to ensure you have not made a typo.