# UITableView Static cells - Selection color not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem regarding my static cells. This is my tableview structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gq1y.png (I cant post images)

The cell background color is `Gray` and the contentView background color is `ClearColor`. The cell is not using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

I set the `Selection` to `Blue` in the storyboad. However, when I run it, the output is `Gray`

I tried doing it manually in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with this code:

```
currentCell.contentView.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor;
```

but it turns out like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfatl.png

The Label in the Cell doesn't change to white and the Accessory background isn't changing. Please help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add the following code to your TableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 // Write code for create your cell and properties regarding that cell
 //add this line 
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];

 return cell;
}
```

Comment: it now works but how can i get the text label to change to white during selection? Take note of the structure of my tableview cell:
Cell -> Content View -> Label & Image. 

Thanks a lot

Comment: i have already got it. i set the cell.textlabel.highlightColor = UIColor whitecolor]. Thanks @Tapansinh

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this selection this way. I have static header cells as 0-index rows in tableview's sections

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("Did select row \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section)")

        if indexPath.row > 0 {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell?.selectionStyle = .gray
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add cell selection stylecolor as stylenone in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 // Write code for create your cell and properties regarding that cell
 //add this line 
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 
 return cell;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that first line be inside the method along with lots of other needed code?

Comment: @katty, I need my selection style to be Blue

Comment: @Katty i have tied ur answer and it doesn't have selection style. but what i want is to change the selection style to blue. however, when i set UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue, it does not work. the selection color displayed is gray.

Comment: Set cell .selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; in  cellForRowAtIndexPath because default cell selected color in gray .and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath change color according to your requirement.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath change contentView.backgroundColor to blue color.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that in iOS 7, using
>
> [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
>
> will not work as expected, because in iOS 7 this is now gray, even if
>   you pass the constant above. See:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle

Vern Jensen's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19257253/2575115