# UITableViewCell highlight only part of the cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, highlighting

I have a standard `UITableViewCell` on which I add a few extra views to in order to create a custom look. One of these such views is a UILabel that I've put a border and background color on, in order for it to look sort of like a separate bubble. When a user taps on the cell, I want it to still highlight, but only on where this `UILabel` is, not the entire cell (it looks ugly when it highlights the whole cell). How can I do this?

Anything with the selection style of the cell seems to only change the color or style, but I want to change the area of the cell that is highlighted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom UITableViewCell selection style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style)

Comment: @rishi That helps, but it seems like the only way is to subclass `UITableViewCell`. Is that the only way?

Comment: Please understand, what you get from the generic `UITableVIewCell` , is just that, a *generic* cell. Meaning, that ANY change you want that is NOT part of a generic cell, you should subclass. Let me add: Subclassing `UITableVIewCell` is something you should not be afraid of. It is a good thing to feel comfortable with and once done, it's easy to make other changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to achieve it is,

1. In `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, check whether the index path of the cell you are rendering is same as `tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow`. If same, give a highlighted look which you want.
2. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` reload the previously selected cell and currently selected cell.
   [You have to cache the previous selected index to reset the highlighted look.]