# How to display selection button when selection style is none in UITableview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I need to set

```
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

in my tableview.I can check multiple cells to delete the rows.While doing this the default image(circle with tickmark) to selection at left is not getting displayed.Its working fine when I am setting selection styles to

```
` UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue
  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray
  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault`
```

My question is there any way to display selection button when selection style is none in tableview ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style
check this answer 
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it with `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault`

If you want to change the selected color of the cell:

```
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:colorView];
```