# NSTableRowView/NSTableCellView how to set custom color to selected row?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to implement custom row color when table row is selected.

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{


    NSInteger selectedRow = [_mainTable selectedRow];

    NSTableCellView *cell = [_mainTable rowViewAtRow:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];

    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;

    NSLog(@"selected");
}
```

But this is not working. I find that Apple documentation very confusing (maybe I am wrong). I am not experienced with Mac programming.

Can someone suggest any solution? Basically I need that selection Color to be transparent.

Comment: @meda do you have idea?

Comment: your question has been already answered.. go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style

Comment: @Rana Tallal this is of Ios.

Comment: you can apply the same logic as ios.. set selectionstyle to non, and on selection change the color to your desired color. and change back with an animation maybe

Comment: @Rana Tallal, yes well I tried and it is now working.

Comment: I am trying with drawSelectionInRect but that is not called.

Comment: It's not just Apple's documentation that is confusing.  How about your topic itself?  You want to colorize what?  Text?  Or cell background?  And you don't even mention whether you are using cell-based or view-based.

Comment: @ElTomato I quote my self "I am trying to implement custom row color when table row is selected."

Comment: @ElTomato and please do not comment if you do not have anything to constructive say. Read question please.

Comment: Thank you all for minus. Especially @ElTomato.

Comment: @Johnny The accepted answer will not properly deselect the row (it needs to be handled manually). To prevent this issue, please try using my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first set tableview selection highlight style to

```
 NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone
```

then in your tablView delegate implement

```
tableView:shouldSelectRow:
```

and write this code inside it:

```
NSTableViewRow *row= [_mainTable rowViewAtRow:selectedRow makeIfNecessary:NO];
row.backgroundColor = [your color];
return YES;
```

read these also 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:rowViewForRow:

for selection style
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTableView/selectionHighlightStyle

Comment: for NSTableRowView I needed to set tableRowView.needsDisplay = YES to ensure the view will be redrawn after changing its color.

Comment: how do you the unselection process?

Comment: Why do you give an iOS sample (UITableViewRow... UI* is iOS only) when being asked about a NSTableView?

Comment: dont know abt now but back then it was the same syntax you just needed to change UI to NS and vice versa it worked

Comment: This leaves all previously-selected rows colored.

Answer (score 15):

**Solution**

This should be done by subclassing `NSTableRowView` and then returning your subclass in with the `NSTableView` delegate method
`-(NSTableRowView*)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row`

Subclassing `NSTableRowView` provides much more flexibility when modifying your row view. Returning your subclass in the `NSTableView` delegate method above
will also automatically remove the background selection color when clicking from one row to the next (which is an open issue in the other answer provided).

---

**Steps**

First, subclass `NSTableRowView` and override `drawSelectionInRect` to change its background color when selected:

```
@implementation MyTableRowView

- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawSelectionInRect:dirtyRect];
    [[NSColor yellowColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

Next, return your subclassed row view using the `rowViewForRow` `NSTableView` delegate method:

```
- (NSTableRowView*)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    static NSString* const kRowIdentifier = @"MyTableRow";
    MyTableRowView* myRowView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:kRowIdentifier owner:self];
    if (!myRowView) {
        myRowView = [[MyTableRowView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
        myRowView.identifier = kRowIdentifier;
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

Using this approach, you can also easily override other elements like the separator color. To do this, override the `drawSeparatorInRect` method in your `NSTableRowView` subclass like so:

```
- (void)drawSeparatorInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Change the separator color if the row is selected
    if (self.isSelected) [[NSColor orangeColor] setFill];
    else [[NSColor grayColor] setFill];
    // Fill the seperator
    dirtyRect.origin.y = dirtyRect.size.height - 1.0;
    dirtyRect.size.height = 1.0;
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

---

**Resources**

Overriding `NSTableRowView` display settings
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstablerowview

NSTableview `rowViewForRow` delegate method
https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1532417-tableview

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is to set the custom color to the selected row and also the highlighted text color. The output should look something like this,

[image]

In the above screenshot, we are doing

> - Setting the background selected color to white
> - Adding the corner radius
> - Changing the text color to blue
> - Adding the blue stroke color

You can do a lot more customization but this answer covers above-mentioned points.

**1. Start with subclassing NSTableRowView**

```
class CategoryTableRowView: NSTableRowView {

override func drawSelection(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    if selectionHighlightStyle != .none {
        let selectionRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
        NSColor(calibratedRed: 61.0/255.0, green: 159.0/255.0, blue: 219.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).setStroke()
        NSColor(calibratedWhite: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).setFill()
        let selectionPath = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: selectionRect, xRadius: 25, yRadius: 25)
        selectionPath.fill()
        selectionPath.stroke()
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Return custom CategoryTableRowView() in the NSTableViewDelegate method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
      return CategoryTableRowView()
}
```

**3. Make sure you have `selectionHighlightStyle` to regular in your ViewController class**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .regular
}
```

**4. To set the textColor, create a subclass of NSTableCellView**

```
class CategoryCellView: NSTableCellView {

@IBOutlet weak var categoryTextField: NSTextField!

override var backgroundStyle: NSView.BackgroundStyle {
    willSet{
        if newValue == .dark {
            categoryTextField.textColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 61.0/255.0, green: 159.0/255.0, blue: 219.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            categoryTextField.textColor = NSColor.black
        }
    }
  }
}
```

override the `backgroundStyle` property and set the desired color for the text.

Note: In my case, I have a custom cell which has a `categoryTextField` outlet.So to set the text color I use:
`categoryTextField.textColor = NSColor.black`

**5. Set custom class inside storyboard**
[image]

I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: For objc you can use override `NSTableCellView.setBackgroundStyle:` to adjust the row based on selection. See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstablecellview/1483206-backgroundstyle?language=objc).