# Changing alpha of UITableViewCell when selected does nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Following the advice in this answer [Custom UITableViewCell selection style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style) about how to make a custom selection style for a `UITableViewCell` I did the following.

First, in my custom view controller, which has a `UITableView` as a property and which serves as its datasource and delegate I have the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //UITableViewCell *cell;
    NavTableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Then this is my entire custom UITableViewCell:

```
#import "NavTableViewCell.h"

@implementation NavTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if(highlighted){
        self.contentView.alpha = .5;
    }else{
        self.contentView.alpha = 1;

    }
}

@end
```

I have also tried putting the code in `setSelected`. In both cases I don't see any change in my selected/highlighted table view cell. I have tried changing its color and changing the colors of the labels within it, but there is simply no change. I have also tried going through all the kinds of selection styles for the cell, all to no avail as far as seeing my customization.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation:

> You can use  **selectedBackgroundView** to give the cell a custom appearance when it is
>   selected. When the cell is selected, **this view is layered above the
>   backgroundView and behind the contentView.**

So whatever you want to do to your cell while selecting it, you have to do it for the `selectedBackgroundView` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIView *highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
highlightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1.0 alpha:.5];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = highlightView;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. That does something but it doesn't achieve the effect I want, which is for the entire contentView and enclosed subviews to change their alpha value.