# how to animate text label color changes during UITableViewCell selection?

Tags: swift, selection, uitableview

I'm trying to create a custom selection style for my table view cells by creating a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. When I click a cell, I want it to change color and fade back to the original color. I've read other posts on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style), but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: `selectionStyle` is set to `.None`.

When I use `setHighlighted(_:)`, the color doesn't change immediately and only happens when the tap lasts for like 0.5 sec.

I've also used `setSelected(_:)`. The color changes right away but won't change back. So I added `deselectRowAtIndexPath(_:)` in `tableView(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` but this causes no changes at all. Then I tried using `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_:)` and finally the color changes and goes back to the original color. But unfortunately it doesn't animate the last part, fading back to the original color. Also I noticed that after the color changed, it also dimms the original color (caused by `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_:)`).

I gave up on using `setSelected(_:)` and `setHighlighted(_:)` and tried using `touchesBegan(_:)` and `touchesEnded(_:)`. To keep it short, same as above...

These are the codes I've tried using (**not all together**).

In the subclass of `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    label.textColor = selected ? UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.blackColor()
}

override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    label.textColor = highlighted ? UIColor.redColor() : UIColor.blackColor()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

    let changeEnded = CATransition()
    changeEnded.duration = 0.5

    nameLabel.layer.addAnimation(changeEnded, forKey: nil)
    nameLabel.textColor = .blackColor()
}
```

In the table view controller (**not together either**):

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

I somehow managed to solve it, but it just doesn't feel like this is how it should be done. Shouldn't it be much simpler to animate such a simple animation for an `UILabel`?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selected = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomViewCell

    let changeColor = CATransition(); changeColor.duration = 1

    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        selected.label.layer.addAnimation(changeColor, forKey: nil)
        selected.label.textColor = .blackColor()
    }

    selected.nameLabel.textColor = .redColor()

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```