# How to disable UITableViewCell highlighting?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a dark gray view background with a transparent tableview. I'm using the following code to try and stop cell highlight when a cell is clicked. It works except right when the cell is initially clicked, I see a highlight. I then transition to another scene after that. When I come back, the cell is not highlighted.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

How do I disable the initial cell highlighting that is still going on?

Comment: Set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

follow this link:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920156/custom-uitableviewcell-selection-style)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set UITableViewCell selection style none

```
cell.selectionStyle = .None
```

Comment: This then requires a double click to select.

Answer (score 5):

`UITableViewDelegate` has methods to deal with cell highlights, probably 
`tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAt:)` is what you are looking for

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:) for the other methods

Answer (score 5):

I found that the other answers did not work for me as they required a double click to select. This did work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Comment: This question requests that the highlight not appear when clicked. This answer does not prevent that visual effect, and it accentuates the visual impact when the selection -> unselected, because it used `animated: true`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to prevent highlighting is setting `selectionStyle` to `None`. Here's how you can achieve this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    return cell
}
```

Comment: NOTE: this is a fast and easy workaround with stock table/cell config, because it is just mapping the highlighted's visual state to the (default) unselected visual state. If you want to truly disable highlighting's events, see answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488665/2910